# Decrypting a short javascript code

Tags: javascript

Ive searched by I cant find a good way to decrypt javascript codes, here is a sample:

```
var _6505=/[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/
```

Ive visited some websites to decrypt but it asks me for the key and i dont have any keys,

thanks.

Comment: This is obfuscation, not encryption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't really "encryption". It's just a string of ASCII characters represented as hexadecimal numbers. `\x41\` is "A", `\x42` is "B", and so on. What you're really looking at is:

```
var _6505 = /[ABCDEF]/;
```

This `_6505` variable is probably used as a regular expression somewhere, given how it's defined between forward-slashes.

Comment: Which is a regex that will match any string containing one of A, B, C, D, E, or F.